# how to deploy .phar library to google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phar

I have an application to deploy to GAE.
My Application contains a library with .phar file.

So, how I need to config to deploy this library to GAE.

I tried extract phar file to use, but it is complicated to use.

Comment: Unfortunately phar is not an extension supported on GAE: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Enabled_extensions

Comment: thanks Mars, I saw it!